# Fabric key needed when installing crashlytics

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am trying to install Crashlytics alongside Firebase into a new clean app, but I am running into some issues. When I follow the instructions on the firebase setup (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started), I get this error when I start the app -

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FABException', reason: '[Fabric] Value of Info.plist key "Fabric" must be a NSDictionary.'

I am assuming this is due to the fabric and crashlytics pods I have included as told to in the get-started link, but because I am going through Firebase rather than fabric, I don't have this key for the Info.plist, or and account with fabric, so I can't add in these details to start the app. Am I doing things the right way? I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong, as I am following all the instructions.

Comment: Register your app on Fabric and get the API key. It is a mandate.

Comment: So I need to make a fabric account to be able to use crashlytics on firebase?

Comment: I think you are using Fabric's crashlytics in your app. If you want to use only Firebase's crashlytics, comment out Fabric code in appDelegate and no need to register on Fabric.

Comment: And since you are using firebase, I would advice you to use Firebase's crashlytics only.

Comment: So when I go through the Firebase tutorial to set up Firebase crashlytics, it tells me to add in 
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.6' 
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.1'

So I'm not sure how I can use firebase crashlytics without using Fabric, and therefore creating a Fabric account

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. Can you share your Firebase init code and any part of your info.plist with Keys and secrets removed?

Comment: I have same issue. But when i use Unit Tests with @testable import for my app. Crash with same error with code "FirebaseApp.configure()" in AppDelegate

Comment: Same issue here, only failing now in FirebaseApp.configure() for unit tests.

Comment: Did anyone manage to fix it while running unit tests? @Augie

Comment: @JoeAlamo  I got it working, but there were a few other tweaks to fabric made so not sure if all of them are needed to get unit testing working.  Anyway, check in app delegate if app is running unit tests and if so do not configure firebaseApp.  The other changes was removing the api keys from fabric Run script and moved that into the method that configured firebaseAppp

Comment: @Augie Thanks for getting back to me. Yep, the checking in app delegate seems to be the way to do it. What I wonder though is: if somewhere in my code I am running Firebase.randomFunction(), what happens during tests if this line gets hit and I have firebase app unconfigured? Will it crash? :/